# Datetime comparison in Python using JSON data

Tags: python, json, datetime

I am writing a script to load json file and pull out the values within a specific time stamp. This is my code.

```
import json,datetime

t1 = "2021-01-28T01:30:00Z"
t2 = "2021-01-29T10:10:00Z"
t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
with open('sample.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for item in data:
        time = item.get('time')
        #timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        while time > t1 and time < t2:
            print(time)
```

The error I am getting is `Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\titto\Desktop\test.py", line 12, in <module> while time > t1 and time < t2: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'`

The JSON format is this one. List of values with the following keys. I want to check for a given time limit and take the total number of true values for each production.

```
{
    "time": "2021-01-29 09:30:00",
    "production_A": false,
    "production_B": false
  },
  {
    "time": "2021-01-29 09:50:00",
    "production_A": true,
    "production_B": false
  },
  {
    "time": "2021-01-29 10:10:00",
    "production_A": true,
    "production_B": true
  },
```

Comment: Use `time = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(item.get('time'))` to make variable `time` also a datetime object.

Comment: @MrFuppes If I want to check for the true values of each production a specific time period say 9 AM to 2 PM for all the days. How will I do that. The given format is in 24hr clock.

Comment: As I understand your `for` loop iterates all the records in your json. Now I think you'll want an `if` statement instead of the `while` loop. If the timestamp falls within your limits, check the production keys and procee if True. On the phone, can't type an actual answer ;-)

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes I corrected it to an if. For example, if I wanna check the data from start = "2021-01-28T06:00:00Z" 
end = "2021-01-29T18:00:00Z" and I want to check for a batch say 6 AM - 2 PM for both days. How can I implement this. The version I tried is I converted 6 AM to `datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")` this format, same for the 2 PM. But this only works on a single day right as I have to give the date also with the format. if the input ranges over 2 days or more this fails. how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Since `time` variable is a string object, you can't compare it with a `datetime` (`t1` and `t2`) objects due to type incompatibility. I think you can fix the error by converting the `time` string to be `datetime.datetime` using the function `datetime.datetime.strptime` or `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat` (as suggested by @MrFuppes). I notice you commented it out but I think you should uncomment it and change it from

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

to

```
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

or

```
time = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(time)
```

```
import json,datetime

t1 = "2021-01-28T01:30:00Z"
t2 = "2021-01-29T10:10:00Z"
t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
with open('sample.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for item in data:
        time = item.get('time')
        time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        while time > t1 and time < t2:
            print(time)
```

When running the script, it will cause an infinite `while` loop, since I think this is your work-in-progress, I didn't remove it. Additionally, another alternative approach is to covert `t1` and `t2` `datetime` objects into string format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` in order to be able to compare with `time` variable

Comment: the format in the OPs json is good ISO8601, you can use [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) for more convenience

Comment: Thanks @MrFuppes for the suggestion, I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks it worked. Now I have improvised the code a little bit to get the total count of  'production_A and 'production_B' like this 
`
if item.get['production_A'] == True:
          countA += 1
         if item.get['production_B'] == True:
          countB += 1
         print(countA,countB)
`
It's showing a error as the object is not `object is not subscriptable`. I am very new to this and only learning.

Comment: @GaiusGD'cruz I think you should use either `item.get(<key>)` or `item[<key>]` in order to get the key `<key>`'s value in the dictionary. I think you are using a combination of both `item.get[<key>]`. In this case, you should use either `item['production_B']` and `item['production_A']` or `item.get('production_B')` and `item.get('production_A')` to get the dictionary value